# orderByValue in child [Firebase Database Android]

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase database

[image]

I need order this list by value of the child "total"
I try to use this code

```
data.child("rating_apps").child("Developing").orderByChild("total").orderByValue().addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                 list.add(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class));
                 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Is it possible to order the list by value which is not close from parents?

Comment: You can only have one `orderBy...` in a query. If you remove the `.orderByValue()` it'll order by the value of the `total` property.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen no. If I remove `orderByValue()`, it'll order by alphabet, not by number

Comment: When you add `orderByValue()` it will order on the value of the wrong property. With just `orderByChild("status")` it sorts on the value of the `status` property. It will indeed sort those values as strings, since you stored your numeric values as strings. If you want them sorted numerically, store them as actual numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one orderBy... in a query. Your `orderByValue()`causes Firebase to order on the value of the wrong property (the keys iirc).

If you remove `orderByValue()` (and thus just have `orderByChild("status")`), Firebase will on the value of the `status` property of each child.

As you noted, it will indeed sort those values as strings, since you stored your numeric values as strings. If you want them sorted numerically, store them as actual numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
Query myTopPostsQuery = databaseReference.child("user-posts").child(myUserId)
        .orderByChild("starCount");
myTopPostsQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    // TODO: implement the ChildEventListener methods as documented above
    // ...
});
```

Comment: There is no difference between this and my code. This code is not ordering the list by value of the child "total"